# Apache 2 /httpd vhost dynamic documentroot

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I have an app in folder /var/www/test
Also there is an "sub-app" in folder /var/www/test/subapp (There is another index.php inside
If user will type test.com the index.php of test should trigger but when user type test.com/triggersubapp the index,php from /var/www/test/subapp shall run.

I failed to create correct  statements and RewriteRules and I haven't got much time left. So have any one of You know how to do this easiest way or maybe have a correct definition?

I would greatly appreciate it !!!

**EDIT**

The main index.php and .htaccess are in /var/www/test/public/. :(

Comment: Is this correct ? `test.com/triggersubapp`  Or is it a typo?

Comment: No it's not a typo. That's just an example I came up with. ;) 
triggersubapp in url should end with DocumentRoot change or maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.htaccess` in root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^triggersubapp/?$    subapp/index.php
```

This will rewrite `triggersubapp`  to `subapp/index.php` which means if user enters `test.com/triggersubapp`   he/she will see result for `test.com/subapp/index.php`

Comment: Thanks for Your help @undone. Sorry but I forgot to mention that the first index.php file is in test/public 
And I think that putting this into root folder of my app wont work. :) 
Is there a way to go one folder back? ../subapp/index.php ?

Comment: `test.com`  should point to `/var/www/test/public/`. `test.com/triggersubapp`  should point to `/var/www/test/subapp`  ??